# why Exponential scientific notation is added in Double

Tags: java

why exponential is added to double in java?
e.g: 10000000 (10^7) in java double : 1.0E7

why this E?

Comment: Java **prints** the double with an exponent (by default). The conversion of a double to a String is non-trivial.

Comment: there is no notation added to `Double`, the number itself does not have a notation; it is the way it is represented (as string) that is using the notation. Maybe you can use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) to get an adequate formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any reason why java adds exponential in double?

Because that's how they defined the [`Double.toString(double d)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) method, as **documented**.

Why did they define it that way?

Because a `double` can store values in range `4.9e-324` (`Double.MIN_VALUE`) to `1.7976931348623157e308` (`Double.MAX_VALUE`). Since it only has about 17 digits of precision, those extreme values would be formatted with around 300 zero's, if not formatted in scientific notation. Would that be useful to see?

Let's see an example. Which of these are more useful?

See question [How many atoms are there in our solar system?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/195522)
Answer: 1.2 ⋅ 10<sup>57</sup>

In Java, that could print as:

- Scientific notation: `1.2E57`
- Decimal notation: `1200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Which of those are easier to read and interpret?

---

**UPDATE**

Why does it switch to scientific notation already at 10<sup>7</sup>?

*Probably* because they wanted `float` and `double` to switch at the same time, and `float` only has about 7 digits of precision. This way it'll never print trailing zeroes caused by lack of precision.